# Как вывести информацию из массива $_SESSION в другом файле?

Tags: php, сессия

Нужна помощь, возможно, в глупом вопросе, но я делаю личный кабинет на сайте, и столкнулся с проблемой. Как мне вывести информацию из массива `$_SESSION` в другом файле?
Объясню подробнее, чтобы было понятно:
данный кусок кода находится в файле `testreg.php`. Третья строка это ссылка на файл `lk.php`. Так вот, когда я использую

```
 "print_r($_SESSION['login']);"
```

в файле `lk.php`, то информация из массива не выводится. Вообще. То есть, пустая страница.
Можно как-то использовать переменные сессии в файле, где о сессиях, скажем так, вообще ничего не сказано?

```
echo "вы вошли как: "; 
print_r($_SESSION['login']);
echo "</br><a href='lk.php'>Личный кабинет</a>";
```

Comment: `session_start()` http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-start.php

Comment: @Vismanв уже делал так, в начале php делал старт сессии, но в скобках ничего не указывал. Может быть, там нужно указать данные из массива $_session?

Comment: `Замечание:

    Для использования сессий на основе cookie, функция session_start() должна быть вызвана перед выводом чего бы то ни было в браузер.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых чтобы вывести что-то из массива используйте `echo`, `print_r()` это все таки больше функция для дампа, во-вторых, вы должны где-то в начале главного файла обьявить `session_start` и потом подключать его во все файлы где вы будете использовать сессии, тогда проблем с доступом не будет, главное несколько раз не продублируйте эту функцию, и удоставерьтесь что в `php.ini` у вас разрешены сессии.
Подробнее про `session_start` и вообще про сесии в официальной [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-start.php).

Ну и на всякий случай, вы же не забывайте заполнить массив `$_SESSION` тем что вам нужно, оно же там из неоткуда не возьмется.

Comment: В начале файла testreg.php и lk.php объявил session_start();
Всё сработало, информация выведена. Однако появилось предупреждение некрасивое: Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent
Знаю, что это связано с отправкой заголовков, но переместить код php выше html не получается, так как в html теге указана кодировка

Comment: Поставтье в до `session_start` функиц `ob_start()` и все у вас заработает.

Comment: А, нет, всё нормально. Всё работает так, как я и хотел. Спасибо!

Comment: Добавьте галочку под ответ, что вас он устраивает, это поможет новичкам в дальнейшем ореинтироватся.

Comment: Добавил. Спасибо ещё раз за качественный ответ.

Comment: Всегда рад помочь.